# XCode 7.3.1, "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a Swift 2.x app that I am trying to use this Obj-C library with:
https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBPing

I have added the header file to my bridging header:

```
#import "GBPing-master/GBPing/GBPing.h"
```

When I am trying to build, I get this linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GBPing",
>   referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.GBPing in Pinger.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GBPingSummary", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.GBPingSummary in Pinger.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have searched for and found some posts about "symbols not found for architecture arm64" but have not been able to get this working.  I am quite new to iOS development, so XCode & Swift are both fairly new to me (and I have never done Obj-C).

Since I am only using .h and .m files from this library, aren't the needed object files supposed to be built from these?  So why is arm64 not supported and how can I fix it?

**Basically, I just need help getting this GBPing library to compile properly in my Swift app so that I can use it...**

Notes: My "Other Linker Flags" setting is empty, but I did try adding $(inherited), which did not help.  I do not want to remove arm64 as an architecture.  Lastly, this is an Enterprise app that will only run on iPad Air 2 and iPad Mini 4 (iOS 9.2 and up)

Comment: @Asdrubal I am building for a physical device (iPad Air 2).  It built just fine until I tried adding this Obj-C library...

Comment: did you check target membership for GBPing.m and GBPingSummary.m for current building target?

Comment: @ABáo I am not sure exactly what to look for, but in GBPing.m there is a pre-compiler if statement that picks CFNetwork.h (for TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED or TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) or CoreServices.h (for everything else).  The files are available to look at here: https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBPing/tree/master/GBPing

Comment: check your target Build Phases ->Compile Sources for make sure did compile for GBPing.m and GBPingSummary.m . I don't thick import CFNetwork.h or CoreServices.h is reason here

Comment: ABáo That was it!  I had not added GBPing.m and GBPingSummary.m to Build Phases ->Compile Sources!  It builds fine now. Thanks! Please submit this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Zek How did you add the source files to your project, that they weren't automatically added to the "Compile Sources" phase? Xcode will typically sort added files automatically, based on file type (i.e., whether "source to compile" or "resource to bundle").

Comment: @NicolasMiari it's Options-> Add to targets in Xcode when You add new sources file. You can chose what target You want add to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your target Build Phases ->Compile Sources to make sure did compile for GBPing.m and GBPingSummary.m.

if not, just add all library .m file to Compile Sources.