# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Microsoft Azure and Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, azure

I have an existing iOS project that was built for Parse. I am currently migrating that project to Microsoft Azure. I have done the **same exact thing** for another project for this client. That worked just fine.

The full error message I get is:

```
"_NSDeletedObjectsKey", referenced from:
  -[MSManagedObjectObserver handleDidSaveNotification:] 
   in MicrosoftAzureMobile(MSManagedObjectObserver.o)

"_NSInsertedObjectsKey", referenced from:
  -[MSManagedObjectObserver handleDidSaveNotification:] 
   in MicrosoftAzureMobile(MSManagedObjectObserver.o)

"_NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification", referenced from:
  -[MSManagedObjectObserver initWithClient:context:] 
   in MicrosoftAzureMobile(MSManagedObjectObserver.o)
  -[MSManagedObjectObserver dealloc] 
   in MicrosoftAzureMobile(MSManagedObjectObserver.o)

"_NSUpdatedObjectsKey", referenced from:
  -[MSManagedObjectObserver handleDidSaveNotification:] 
   in MicrosoftAzureMobile(MSManagedObjectObserver.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MicrosoftAzureMobile(MSCoreDataStore.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MicrosoftAzureMobile(MSCoreDataStore.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The basic problem workflow is:

1. I have an app that builds just fine.
2. I add the MicrosoftAzureMobile.framework to the project.
3. The app now fails to build with the aforementioned error.
4. I remove the MicrosoftAzureMobile.framework from the project.
5. The app builds just fine again.

I have looked at all kinds of potential fixes to this problem.

- [This is not my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363526/xcode-7-3-1-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64) (at least, in the project where this works, this isn't required)
- The .framework file has its target membership set correctly.
- The .framework is included in the "Link Binary with Libraries" section of "Build Phases"

I have checked every single thing I can think of, even going so far as to run a `grep -rin "MicrosoftAzureMobile" .` command on both projects. As far as I can tell, all of the files, settings, etc. are **exactly** the same between projects. I am even using the same copy of the MicrosoftAzureMobile.framework file, just in case a different compiled version might have made a difference.

Is it possible that an older version of Xcode might make a difference? I cannot remember, but it is possible that I used Xcode 7 for the first project migration, whereas I am currently trying to use Xcode 8 Beta 1 (8T29o). Can anybody think of any other potential causes for this problem? I am really doubting that it has to do with the *.framework file itself.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the Azure SDK requires CoreData. Once I looked up the "missing" classes, that became apparent. Adding the `CoreData` framework fixed this issue, though I thought I had tried that solution before.